# Find app selected on share sheet android

Tags: android, android-sharing

I have given share content share facility on my app user is sharing also but 
I want to find out on which social media app they are sharing most ?

I am using **Intent.createChooser**

Answer (score 0):

Android native share triggers the possible sharing apps installed in the device through Intent. This process is asynchronous and you won't have control over them. If you want to track down counting for shares better go with the customized share options using query intent.